# FWER correction for paired t-test

Tags: paired-comparisons, familywise-error

I have a continuous variable, and a small sample of 8 observations at 4 different time points (before some intervention, and at 3 follow-up time points). My sample, being a preliminary experiment, does not give me enough power to run a mixed model or a GEE model. I see graphically that there are differences at all 3 time points, compared to baseline (a decrease of the response). When I run a mixed model, only the 1st follow-up is significantly different than the baseline, with the 2nd having a p-value of 0.06 and the 3rd, with a smaller effect, is not significant (can be seen graphically that the effect is smaller). I tried running a paired t-test separately for each time point (compared to baseline). The first 2 test were statistically significant (as the graph suggested) and the 3rd not (although the graph does show some effect). My question to you is, should I apply some multiple hypothesis testing correction in this case ? Using the Bonfferoni correction doesn't change the outcome, still 2 tests are signigifant. I just want to do it properly. I am quite confident that with an addition of a few samples also the 3rd time point would have been significant. Is my analysis valid at all ?

Comment: what I meant to say is that with an addition the mix model would give significant result. With more parameters to estimate, the mix model doesn't have enough power with n=8

Comment: Do you have complete data at all time points? Hopefully you do since it is an experiment!

Comment: Yes, I do. I have 8 subjects and 4 time points for each (including baseline). 32 data points.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that you have enough power for mixed models or GEE, but rather than you do not have a high enough sample size to confirm if your data/models meet all of the assumptions. Or the model estimation might not even converge on a solution.

Your best bet would (probably) be to run a repeated-measures ANOVA, then following a significant omnibus test, perform your pairwise comparisons. Apparently there is some debate about how to do this for repeated samples because of the between-group dependence. You certainly would not be committing an error if you performed multiple paired t-tests and adjusted for multiple comparisons (Holm will be better than Bonferroni because it always has more power; see the multcomp package in R).

Also, if you change over time is relatively simple (e.g. linear), you could consider doing a regression.